# Creating D3 Line Graph Based off of Drop-down selection

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, d3.js

I am trying to create a D3 line graph that will display a graph specific to the item that is selected in the drop-down menu. I have one script that queries my MySQL database and fills a drop-down menu with all of the correct options. From there, I want to click on an option and go to another page that creates a line graph based off of that selection. When I click on an option, I use `json_encode` to create a JSON object that should be compatible with D3.

I have another script that deals completely with drawing the graph and try to use `d3.json` to get the JSON object that is created when the specific selection is clicked. Whenever I try to load the graph page, it is completely blank. I am not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible. I have not tried including the drop-down in the same script as the one that creates the graph but do not think that I will be able to get the information from the database the same way.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I can post the code later if it is determined what I am trying to do is possible. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is the script that queries my database for the users that are put in the drop-down menu and then queries the database again for that selection's data. The drop-down menu has the desired result and the data is correctly echoed as well.

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['name']))

 {
  $out = $_POST['name'];

  $temp = explode(",", $out);

  $populate_selection = "SELECT id, lastname, firstname FROM users WHERE id != '$temp[0]' ORDER BY  lastname";

  $out = $temp[1] . ', ' . $temp[2];

   $student_hours = "SELECT ai_averages.user_id, ai_averages.title, ai_averages.hours FROM ai_averages INNER JOIN users ON ai_averages.user_id = users.id WHERE $temp[0] = ai_averages.user_id";

  } 

  else 
     {

 $temp[0] = " ";

 $populate_selection = "SELECT id, lastname, firstname FROM users ORDER BY lastname";
 $student_hours = "SELECT ai_averages.user_id, ai_averages.title, ai_averages.hours FROM ai_averages INNER JOIN users ON ai_averages.user_id = users.id WHERE $temp[0] = ai_averages.user_id";

  $out = " ";
      }

$result = $mysqli->query($populate_selection);

 $option = "<option value= '{$temp[0]}'>$out</option>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$option .= "<option value = '{$row['id']}, {$row['lastname']}, {$row['firstname']}'>{$row['lastname']}, {$row['firstname']} </option>";
 }

if($student_results = $mysqli->query($student_hours))
{ 
$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($student_results); $x++)
  {

      //this array contains the data that I want in my graph
      //the correct data is echoed every time that I click on the different choices
$data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($student_results);
  }

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
 ?>

 <form id = "hello" method = "POST" >
 <select name = "name" onchange = 'this.form.submit()'> <?php echo $option; ?> </select>
 </form>
```

I then try and use `d3.json("filename.php", etc)` to get the information from the `$data` array but this has not worked.

Comment: if you could provide a jsfiddle it would be much easier to help

Comment: I agree with @tomtomtom, as your idea sounds achievable.

Comment: If you're useing d3.json you have to load a .json file in order to read it

Comment: You can load a .php file as well as long as there is a variable of JSON type in that file. I have done this before and that is why I am unsure why this is not working.